# Is there any way to clear XHR cache data on client?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, xmlhttprequest, jqxhr

Using javascript or its libraries is there any way to clear cached XHR data on client?

I want to test my app on few localhosts, wanted to clear XML HTTP Requests on client rather than on server, is there any way?

Comment: `jQuery.ajax({url: ...., cache: false});`.

Comment: Just add a `Cache-Control: no-cache;` header to the HTTP response. No change on the client needed.

Answer (score 0):

easy solution simple adds some extra parameters at the end eg:
original

```
http://yoursite.com/index.html
```

and avoiding cache

```
http://yoursite.com/index.html?rnd=123456
```